# Right way to use groupby resample aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some data which I'm trying to groupby "name" first and then resample by "transaction_date"

```
transaction_date    name    revenue
01/01/2020          ADIB    30419
01/01/2020          ADIB    1119372
01/01/2020          ADIB    1272170
01/01/2020          ADIB    43822
01/01/2020          ADIB    24199
```

The issue i have is writing groupby resample in two different ways return two different results

```
1-- df.groupby("name").resample("M", on="transaction_date").sum()[['revenue']].head(12)

2-- df.groupby("name").resample("M", on="transaction_date").aggregate({'revenue':'sum'}).head(12)
```

The first method returns the values I'm looking for.

I don't understand why the two methods return different results. Is this a bug?

```
Result 1
name    transaction_date    revenue 
ADIB    2020-01-31          39170943.0
        2020-02-29          48003966.0
        2020-03-31          32691641.0
        2020-04-30          11979337.0
        2020-05-31          35510726.0
        2020-06-30          25677857.0
        2020-07-31          12437122.0
        2020-08-31          4348936.0
        2020-09-30          10547188.0
        2020-10-31          5287406.0
        2020-11-30          4288930.0
        2020-12-31          17066105.0

Result 2
name    transaction_date    revenue
ADIB    2020-01-31          64128331.0
        2020-02-29          54450014.0
        2020-03-31          45636192.0
        2020-04-30          25016777.0
        2020-05-31          11941744.0
        2020-06-30          15703151.0
        2020-07-31          5517526.0
        2020-08-31          4092618.0
        2020-09-30          4333433.0
        2020-10-31          3944117.0
        2020-11-30          6528058.0
        2020-12-31          5718196.0
```

Comment: It would be beneficial If You post raw data and output data in code please:-)

Comment: @ipj I've added the raw data and results in there! Sorry, SO amateur here

Comment: The sample data you provide is very limited - doesn't seem to produce the output you're seeing. Could you provide more sample data, please?

Comment: When using the two methods on dummy data, I'm getting identical results.

Comment: @Roy2012 The raw data is 1552 rows. Calendar dates extend for the entire year and there and 11 unique names. No null values present in the dataset. I'm not sure why I'm seeing this odd behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it's either a bug or an extremely strange behavior. Consider the following data:

```
input: 

        date   revenue name
0 2020-10-27  0.744045  n_1
1 2020-10-29  0.074852  n_1
2 2020-11-21  0.560182  n_2
3 2020-12-29  0.208616  n_2
4 2020-05-03  0.325044  n_0

gb = df.groupby("name").resample("M", on="date")

gb.aggregate({'revenue':'sum'})

==>
              revenue
name date                
n_0  2020-12-31  0.325044
n_1  2020-05-31  0.744045
     2020-06-30  0.000000
     2020-07-31  0.000000
     2020-08-31  0.000000
     2020-09-30  0.000000
     2020-10-31  0.074852
n_2  2020-10-31  0.560182
     2020-11-30  0.208616


print(gb.sum()[['revenue']])
==>
                  revenue
name date                
n_0  2020-05-31  0.325044
n_1  2020-10-31  0.818897
n_2  2020-11-30  0.560182
     2020-12-31  0.208616
```

As one can see, it seems that aggregate produces the wrong results. For example, it takes data from Oct and attaches it to May.

Here's an even simpler example:

Data frame:

```
        date  revenue name
0 2020-02-24        9  n_1
1 2020-05-12        8  n_2
2 2020-03-28        9  n_2
3 2020-01-14        2  n_0

gb = df.groupby("name").resample("M", on="date")

res1 = gb.sum()[['revenue']]

==>
name date               
n_0  2020-01-31        2
n_1  2020-02-29        9
n_2  2020-03-31        9
     2020-04-30        0
     2020-05-31        8

res2 = gb.aggregate({'revenue':'sum'})

==>
name date               
n_0  2020-05-31        2
n_1  2020-01-31        9
n_2  2020-02-29        8
     2020-03-31        9
```

I opened a bug about it: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35173

Comment: That's right! I've noticed if I sum up the (incorrect) monthly values ... it adds up for the year. Which agrees with your point - it seems to be moving data around between months! Strange!

Comment: I've found that `gb.aggregate('sum')['revenue']` works ok. I'm curious how the bug will be resolved.

Comment: @ipj That's true ... that works well! if you had different aggregate functions for each column ... you'd have a problem